# "what+noun" can take modifiers when asking?

Tags: questions, questions-v-relatives

can I ask questions in this way?

"What food made in that factory made you sick?"

"what kind of man-eating animals living in the reality are the most dangerous?"

or say:"You should know how terribly harmful the food is!"

Comment: The answer is probably **Yes**, but what exactly is the question? Note that *living in the reality* doesn't seem to be idiomatically valid. What's it supposed to mean?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  Someone told me you can't put too many modifiers in the structure, is that true? Do these two sentences make sense or not?

Comment: Those are all fine. The only limit on the number of modifiers that may be attached to any noun is the limit imposed by the reader's tolerance.

Comment: I sense the germ of _Squishy Style..._

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks  so much for your kind help! But a native speaker they don't put everything in one simple sentence. But it won't make the subject too long? I know sometimes you should avoid making the subject too long...

Comment: @P.E.Dant All style is squishy.

Comment: Of course you can make a subject (or anything else) too long; but that is a matter of taste and style, not of grammar.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks so much for your help! But these two sentences are ok?

Comment: Indeed they are, grammatically; but as FumbleFingers tells you, "living in the reality" isn't idiomatic English. You probably mean something like "actually existing", which would be placed **before** *man-eating animals*.

Comment: The advice to keep subjects simple is likely just because there is a tendency for many non-native speakers to make sentences unnecessarily complicated, while native speakers tend towards the simplest constructions that still fully convey the idea.  It doesn't mean complicated constructions are wrong.

Comment: For example, "living in the reality" doesn't add anything to your second sentence, so a native speaker would omit it.  If you meant it to exclude fictional animals, you don't need to have it at all - "what animals" would implicitly exclude fictional creatures unless you specifically included them, such as "what animals, real or imaginary, ...".  If you meant it to exclude extinct animals, the verb in the present tense does that already.  It's not the increase in modifiers that makes the sentence awkward, but the increase in unnecessary modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask what + noun because *what* is an adjective modifying the noun. Furthermore, "What food made in the factory" is a noun clause used as the subject of the sentence. Noun clauses act as nouns and are usually introduced with words like *that, what, whatever, how, who*, etc.

> "What food made in that factory made you sick?" [the direct object of the verb is "sick" and the indirect object is "you."]

**What**. *adj*.

a —used as an interrogative expressing inquiry about the identity, nature, or value of a person, object, or matter <*what minerals do we export*>

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what

---

> "What kind of man-eating animals living in the reality are the most
>   dangerous?"

What | kind | of man-eating animals | living | in the reality | are | the | most | dangerous

Subject: kind

verb: are

predicate adjective: dangerous

In addition to the subject, verb, predicate adjective, and the adjective "What," there are two prepositional phrases, one present participle, and one adverb in the sentence.

Instead of saying "in the reality" you might want: "in the present" or "at the present time."

---

> You should know how terribly harmful the food is!

Here the direct object is a noun clause, but unlike your question, here it is used as a direct object [recall, a direct object is a noun or pronoun that receives the action of the verb]

You | should know | how terribly harmful the food is [the food is terribly harmful; it is how harmful, where "how" modifies the verb in the clause "is."

**How**. *adv*.

: in what manner or way : by what means

: for what reason

: to what degree, extent, or amount

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/how

Noun clause

http://www.studyandexam.com/types-of-subordinate-clause.html

See page 99

http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/AL/HooverCity/SpainParkHigh/Uploads/Forms/Start%20Holt%20Handbook%2010.pdf